# R9 280X crashing

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

So, I'm running a mining Rig with 3 Gigabyte R9 280X's.

I'll start by listing the hardware/software:

**Hardware**

---

- CPU: [AMD Athlon X3](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103911)
- Motherboard: [ASUS Crosshair V Formula-Z](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131876)
- Video Card: [3 Gigabyte R9 280X's 3GB](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125490)
- RAM: 1 stick of 4GB 1600 Mhz
- Hard Drive: 1TB
- Power Supply: 1600W Gold PSU
- OS: Windows 7 x64 SP1

When I run CGMiner it starts up normally:

[image]

Then it starts warming up and you can see GPU 1 gets hotter than the others:

[image]

Then it gets hotter, it gets to about 80 before it crashes:

[image]

Instantly the temperature on GPU 1 drops like 15 degrees and then keeps dropping:

[image]

Then my screens goes black and when it comes back on I get an error message saying the graphics driver has stopped responding and has recovered.

[image]

CGMiner keeps working normally for a minute or two and then crashes.

[image]

This is what's left after it crashes.

[image]

So it looks like GPU 1 crashes and then goes idle. (after a little while, the fan completely shuts off. After a little while longer it comes back on again)

After that I can run CGMiner and it will run normally except GPU 1 will be off, only GPU 0 and 2 will be doing work.

Only GPU 0 has a monitor connected to it and the cars are not connected to each other through Crossfire X.

What could be causing this? Is it a bad graphics card?

Comment: This isn't really on topic here.  Your main problem is cgminer likely hasn't been updated to handle the newer AMD cards.  What other miners have you tried that still support GPU mining?  Have you posted this in the litecoin community, you basically need to find a fork of cgminer, that actually has been updated recently.

Comment: I'm troubleshooting my computer hardware, I can't think of a better place to do that than here. Anyway, I want to download the newest version of cgminer but I can't the website is down. Edit: Nevermind it's not down anymore.

Comment: Also, updating to 3.7.2, the latt version to support GPU mining, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I can think of a much better place http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah, I went there, but the problems isn't with cgminer, I think it's with the video card, so why would I ask there?

Comment: If you think that then do a warranty claim on them.

Comment: But I don't know if it's actually a problem with the GPU yet, no one's given me a useful answer on here -.-

Comment: Might be insufficient cooling. In addition, I recall that there's a LOT of variability in cooling and heat generation with the R9s, and it may be a firmware thing. Its almost NEVER an issue but here, I'd look at my case. I'd also switch around the position of the GPUs to work out if its the cooling system, or the GPU thats at fault. In this particular scenario, I suspect side fans would be a VERY good idea. I disagree with ramhound here that its off topic. I do think more testing is needed.

Comment: I've done tons more testing, cooling isn't an issue at all. They aren't mounted in a case so there's nothing to restrict airflow. All 3 GPU's are suspended above the motherboard with PCI-E extension cables and they're in a cold garage. Cooling literally can't be any better. Now the temperatures never break 75 C, but the GPU's still crash, and it's not always GPU 1 anymore either, 0 and 2 crash as well.

Comment: You essentially have a bunch of 250W heaters. A "cold garage" isn't going to have any effect at all - ambient temperatures don't have a great effect on cooling at such high temperatures and with so much heat being dissipated. It might take a bit longer to heat up, but won't cool appreciably faster. As far as airflow goes, a case can have *better* airflow than just sitting in the open - a good case design is supposed to funnel cool air in from the front/side and hot air out the back. GPU fans sitting in the open tend to leave a 'cloud' of hot air hanging there.

Comment: Adding more physical separation between the cards can help, though. Also consider setting up a larger fan just to keep the air moving past the cards. Many cases that do well with one or two cards would probably end up being too cramped with three.

Comment: Did I not mention that I have a large fan that moves a lot of ait in the room pointed towards the computers? Thanks for the information anyway, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like GPU 1 is getting toasted between 0 and 2.

Test that GPU by removing the other two and running it on its own for a bit. If that fixes it, get a powered PCI-E riser. This will allow you to move the card away from the extra heat of the other two.

Comment: They are all suspended on Risers. After a lot of testing, it's not always 1 that crashes, sometimes 0 or 2 crash as well, so it's not that.